# Move a product-review summary below add to cart button

Tags: magento2, catalog, product-review

I want to move `product-review-summary` in `products listing` page above the price which is at the bottom of product-information. that is after add to cart button . How should I do this? 
[image]
[image]

what is the name of the xml file I should edit.? and what is the block and destination names to give in move command?

Comment: You have to override list.phtml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml` in your theme and move this text

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

after your `product actions product-item-actions` div.

Comment: Thank you let me confirm the overriding path its magento_catalog/templates/list.phtml

Comment: It should be Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: In side bar ilter for removing all items I overrided sidebar.phtml from Magento_Catalog/templates/product/compare/sidebar.phtml but frontend not changing

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? or raise a new question for this?